# Ruby date format validation

Tags: ruby

How I can verify that the date '2016-01-01' is in the right format (%Y-%m-%d).

For example I want to get `true` or `false` if the date is in the right format.

pseudo code:

```
if ('2016-01-01' == (%Y-%m-%d))
    puts date is valid
else
    puts date is not valid
end
```

Please help,

Thanks!

Comment: Do you just want to check the syntax or also the values, e.g. would you consider `2016-02-30` a valid date?

Comment: How about a regexp validation `'2016-01-01'.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/) => nil or MatchData`. ?

Comment: @Stefan i want to check if 2016-02-30 in the valid format of %Y-%m-%d

Comment: @user6801385 well, it depends. On the one hand, each individual value is valid: `2016` is a valid year, `02` is a valid month, and `30` is a valid day. But on the other hand, [February 30](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/February_30) is not a valid date and you can't parse `2016-02-30` using `%Y-%m-%d`. Please clarify your requirements.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

It seems like you are not only interested in the format of the string but also if the string represents a valid date (for example `2016-01-32` is invalid):

```
require 'date'

def validate_date(string)
  format_ok = string.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/)
  parseable = Date.strptime(string, '%Y-%m-%d') rescue false

  if string == 'never' || format_ok && parseable
    puts "date is valid"
  else
    puts "date is not valid"
  end
end

validate_date('2016-01-01')
#=> "date is valid"

validate_date('2016-01-32')
#=> "date is not valid"

validate_date('01-01-2016')
#=> "date is not valid"

validate_date('never')
#=> "date is valid"

validate_date('today')
#=> "date is not valid"
```

Or (would return `true` or `false`):

```
require 'date'

def valid_date?(string)
  return true if string == 'never'

  !!(string.match(/\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}/) && Date.strptime(string, '%Y-%m-%d'))
rescue ArgumentError
  false
end

valid_date?('2016-01-01')
#=> true

valid_date?('2016-01-32')
#=> false

valid_date?('01-01-2016')
#=> false

valid_date?('never')
#=> true

valid_date?('today')
#=> false
```

Note: `Date.strptime` raises an exception for invalid dates, therefore the `rescue false` is required to return `false` in those a cases.

Comment: Note that `strptime` allows extraneous characters, e.g. `valid_date?('2016-01-01 foo-bar')` would return `true`.

Comment: @spickermann thank you, do you know why when I am passing '2016-01-01' I get "date is not valid" ?

Comment: both `valid_date?('2016-01-01') and valid_date?('2016-01-32')` return date is not valid

Comment: Did you copy the whole method from my answer, including all parentheses and the `require 'date'`?

Comment: ok, i think i have a problem with my script, just a sec, im checking, thank u

Comment: ok so im passing the date from aws ec2 tag like this 
`tag_expiration = Facter::Util::Resolution.exec("ec2-describe-tags --region #{region} --filter \"resource-id=#{instance.id}\" --filter key=Expiration | cut -f 5")` , the result of my tag is `01-01-2016`, and this one return valid when im passing it to the method `valid_date?(tag_expiration)` do you know why ?

Comment: If your tag looks like `01-01-2016` then you should not try to parse it with `'%Y-%m-%d'`. Perhaps `'%d-%m-%Y'` would be more appropriate?

Comment: i checked it again, `valid_date?('01-01-2016') return 'date is valid'`,
`valid_date?('2016-01-01') return date is valid` and
`valid_date?('2016-01-32') return date is not valid`

Comment: I wanted to make sure that if that date is not in the format of `2016-01-30` or `yyyy-month-day` it will return date is not valid

Comment: I checked `01-01-2016` because I wanted to see if its works

Comment: I updated my answer to address that issue. Now it checks both the format and if it is a valid date.

Comment: cool !!! it works, last question how I can do the same this but add into it that also the string "never" is a valid date ?

Answer (score 7):

Since the context of the question was not strictly specified I will add one possible solution in the context of Rails. I have found `iso8601` method to be useful, which would check if a string is a valid iso8601 date and would raise exception if it is not. 
http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveSupport/TimeZone.html#method-i-iso8601

```
def validate_date(date)
  Date.iso8601(date.to_s)
  return true
rescue ArgumentError
  false
  # although, in my case I felt that logging this error and raising exception was a better approach, since we are forwarding this to the user of our API.
  # log_and_raise_error("Given argument is not a valid ISO8601 date: '#{date}'")
end
```

Answer (score 2):

```
require 'date'

def date_valid?(date)
  format = '%Y-%m-%d'
  DateTime.strptime(date, format)
  true
rescue ArgumentError
  false
end

p date_valid?('2016-01-01') # true
p date_valid?('2016-25-10') # false
```

Comment: thank you, I saw that you and @spickermann answered on the same time, I really appreciate this, but somehow it doesn't work, I comment above.

Comment: `01-01-2016` return true, and this is not what I need :/